# How to change default optimization in spotlight from pytorch e.g. torch.optim.SGD?

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-factorization

I'm currently using spotlight https://github.com/maciejkula/spotlight/tree/master/spotlight
to implement Matrix Factorization in recommender system. spotlight is based on pytorch, it's a integrated platform implementing RS. In spotlight/factorization/explicit, it uses torch.optim.Adam as optimizer, I want to change it to torch.optim.SGD.
I tried

```
emodel = ExplicitFactorizationModel(n_iter=15,
                                embedding_dim=32, 
                                use_cuda=False,
                                loss='regression',
                                l2=0.00005,
                                optimizer_func=optim.SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9))
```

but it gives:TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'params'
Any suggestions?

Comment: Try passing it without any argument such as `optimizer_func=optim.SGD` only _(also without brackets ())_.

Comment: I tried before.Won't work, give: ValueError: parameter group didn't specify a value of required optimization parameter lr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `partial` from `functools` to first set the learning rate and momentum and then pass this class to `ExplicitFactorizationModel`. Something like:

```
from functools import partial
SDG_fix_lr_momentum = partial(torch.optim.SGD, lr=0.001, momentum=0.9)
emodel = ExplicitFactorizationModel(n_iter=15,
                                embedding_dim=32, 
                                use_cuda=False,
                                loss='regression',
                                l2=0.00005,
                                optimizer_func=SDG_fix_lr_momentum)
```